# Altering more than one value in a two dimentional list with loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

The program I'm writing is to "sell" seats in a theater after creating the seats as a 5 row 5 column two dimensional list. I've gotten it to work for the most part but if I choose a seat next to one that has been marked as sold, I get the message as if that seat was sold as well. 
Here is the criteria I am working with:

> Fill a 5 x 5 grid. Then do the following. Create a loop that will
>   continue until the user says (Y/N) they want to quit, or all 25 seats
>   are sold. Have the users ask for a seat position based on row and
>   column (row, column) - remember that the list’s positions start at 0,
>   but the user will ask for the seat starting at row or column position
>   1.  Then when the user selects the seat, print out the user's price and mark an 'SS' (sold seat) in the List where the price was.  Then
>   print out all the seats so the user can select another. When the next
>   user in the loop, asks for a seat make sure you check and see if that
>   seat is already sold (has an ‘SS’ in the table). If it is sold, tell
>   the user – otherwise return the price and mark the seat sold.  After
>   the user asks to quit or all the seats are sold, or the loop ends,
>   then printout the list as shown below - showing the sold seats (SS)
>   and unsold seats (the unsold seat should still have a price).

And here is my Code:

```
def main():
seatList = [
    [50,50,50,50,50],
    [40,45,45,45,40],
    [30,35,35,35,30],
    [20,20,20,20,20],
    [10,10,10,10,10],
]
cont = "y"
while cont.lower() == "y":
    print("Here is the seating arrangement:")
    availableSeat = seatPrinter(seatList)
    totalRow = int(len(seatList)) - 1
    totalColumn = int(len(seatList[0])) - 1
    seatRow = int(input("Please enter a row number (1 to %d):"%totalRow))
    seatColumn = int(input("Please enter a seat number (1 to %d):"%totalColumn))
    seatStatus = seatAvailable(seatList, seatRow, seatColumn)
    cont = input("Would you like to reserve another seat?(Y/N)")

def seatPrinter(seats):
    for i in range(len(seats[0])):
        print(seats[i])

def seatAvailable(seats, row, column):
    for i in range(len(seats)):
        for j in range(len(seats)):
            if seats[i][j] is not 'SS':
                seats[i][j] = 'SS'
                print("Your seat is in row %d seat number %d"%(i+1, j+1))
                return
            else:
                print("Sorry, that seat isn't available.")
                return

main()
```

As it is now, this is the output I get:

```
Here is the seating arrangement:
[50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
[40, 45, 45, 45, 40]
[30, 35, 35, 35, 30]
[20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
Please enter a row number (1 to 4):1
Please enter a seat number (1 to 4):1
Your seat is in row 1 seat number 1
Would you like to reserve another seat?(Y/N)y
Here is the seating arrangement:
['SS', 50, 50, 50, 50]
[40, 45, 45, 45, 40]
[30, 35, 35, 35, 30]
[20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
Please enter a row number (1 to 4):1
Please enter a seat number (1 to 4):2
Sorry, that seat isn't available.
Would you like to reserve another seat?(Y/N)
```

I can't seem to find why I can't reserve more seats in the same row, any help is appreciated

Comment: You donot have to use for loop to check seat availability, just use index row and col/.

Comment: Ah that is so much better! Thanks. I realized too after re reading this I hadn't yet added in the part about stopping if all seats are sold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def main():
    seatList = [
        [50,50,50,50,50],
        [40,45,45,45,40],
        [30,35,35,35,30],
        [20,20,20,20,20],
        [10,10,10,10,10],
    ]
    cont = "y"
    while cont.lower() == "y":
        print("Here is the seating arrangement:")
        availableSeat = seatPrinter(seatList)
        totalRow = int(len(seatList)) - 1
        totalColumn = int(len(seatList[0])) - 1
        seatRow = int(input("Please enter a row number (1 to %d):"%totalRow))
        seatColumn = int(input("Please enter a seat number (1 to %d):"%totalColumn))
        seatStatus = seatAvailable(seatList, seatRow, seatColumn)
        cont = input("Would you like to reserve another seat?(Y/N)")

def seatPrinter(seats):
    for i in range(len(seats[0])):
        print(seats[i])

def seatAvailable(seats, row, column):
    if seats[row-1][column-1] is not 'SS':
        seats[row-1][column-1] = 'SS'
        print("Your seat is in row %d seat number %d"%(row,column))
        return
    else:
        print("Sorry, that seat isn't available.")
        return

main()
```

Result,

```
Here is the seating arrangement:
[50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
[40, 45, 45, 45, 40]
[30, 35, 35, 35, 30]
[20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
Please enter a row number (1 to 4):1
Please enter a seat number (1 to 4):1
Your seat is in row 1 seat number 1
Would you like to reserve another seat?(Y/N)Y
Here is the seating arrangement:
['SS', 50, 50, 50, 50]
[40, 45, 45, 45, 40]
[30, 35, 35, 35, 30]
[20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
Please enter a row number (1 to 4):1
Please enter a seat number (1 to 4):2
Your seat is in row 1 seat number 2
Would you like to reserve another seat?(Y/N)Y
Here is the seating arrangement:
['SS', 'SS', 50, 50, 50]
[40, 45, 45, 45, 40]
[30, 35, 35, 35, 30]
[20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
Please enter a row number (1 to 4):1
Please enter a seat number (1 to 4):1
Sorry, that seat isn't available.
Would you like to reserve another seat?(Y/N)
```